# Perfect forwarding class variadic parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I have a class with variadic type parameters. Inside that class I have a method that takes arguments of those types, makes a tuple of them and stores them in a vector. What I want is to use perfect forwarding to avoid unnecessary copies. I solved it by prefixing the method with another variadic template and I forward these new types instead of old ones, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Let me show you an example of my code:

```
template<typename ... Tlist>
class A{
public:
    template<typename ... Xlist>
    void method(Xlist && ... plist){
        // some code 
        std::vector<std::tuple<Tlist...>> vec;
        vec.push_back(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Xlist>(plist)...));
        // some other code
    }

};
```

This works with correct types and it doesn't compile with incorrect types anyway so I guess it's ok. But what I'd like is to somehow use the `Tlist` types in method header, something like this:

```
template<typename ... Tlist>
class A{
public:
    void method(Tlist && ... plist){
        // some code 
        std::vector<std::tuple<Tlist...>> vec;
        vec.push_back(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Tlist>(plist)...));
        // some other code
    }

};
```

But that only works with rvalues.

So is there a way to avoid using another template while still making perfect forwarding possible?

Comment: It wouldn't be perfect forwarding... the value category would be determined by the class template arguments, not by the value category of the actual parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt: So you're saying that the first approach is ok, while nothing like the second approach is possible?

Comment: The second approach is possible.  It will compile and run correctly.  But it will not propagate (forward) the value category of the actual arguments onward to `make_tuple`.

Comment: Yeah but it will copy everything (when modified to actually work), whereas the first approach at least use moves where possible.

Comment: Why not use `void method(Tlist... plist)` ?  That way parameters intended for by-value tuple members get copied/moved during the call to your function.  Then inside your function, make sure they get moved (use `std::move` or `std::forward<Tlist&&>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the problem is simply to take a pack of values, and `move` from them:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct A{
  void method(Ts...ts){
    // some code 
    std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(ts)...));
    // some other code
  }
};
```

the above doesn't behave well if `Ts` contain references, but neither did your original code.  It also forces a redundant `move`, which for some types is expensive.  Finally, if you didn't have a backing `vec`, it forces your types to be **moveable** -- the solutions below do not.

This is by far the simplest solution to your problem, but it doesn't actually perfect forward.

---

Here is a more complex solution.  We start with a bit of metaprogramming.

`types` is a bundle of types:

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
```

`conditional_t` is a C++14 alias template to make other code cleaner:

```
// not needed in C++14, use `std::conditional_t`
template<bool b, class lhs, class rhs>
using conditional_t = typename std::conditional<b,lhs,rhs>::type;
```

`zip_test` takes one test template, and two lists of types.  It tests each element of `lhs` against the corresponding element of `rhs` in turn.  If all pass, it is `true_type`, otherwise `false_type`.  If the lists don't match in length, it fails to compile:

```
template<template<class...>class test, class lhs, class rhs>
struct zip_test; // fail to compile, instead of returning false

template<
  template<class...>class test,
  class L0, class...lhs,
  class R0, class...rhs
>
struct zip_test<test, types<L0,lhs...>, types<R0,rhs...>> :
  conditional_t<
    test<L0,R0>{},
    zip_test<test, types<lhs...>, types<rhs...>>,
    std::false_type
  >
{};

template<template<class...>class test>
struct zip_test<test, types<>, types<>> :
  std::true_type
{};
```

now we use this on your class:

```
// also not needed in C++14:
template<bool b, class T=void>
using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;
template<class T>
using decay_t=typename std::decay<T>::type;

template<class...Ts>
struct A{
  template<class...Xs>
  enable_if_t<zip_test<
    std::is_same,
    types< decay_t<Xs>... >,
    types< Ts... >
  >{}> method(Xs&&... plist){
    // some code 
    std::vector<std::tuple<Tlist...>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(
      std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Xlist>(plist)...)
    );
    // some other code
  }
};
```

which restricts the `Xs` to be exactly the same as the `Ts`.  Now we probably want something slightly different:

```
  template<class...Xs>
  enable_if_t<zip_test<
    std::is_convertible,
    types< Xs&&... >,
    types< Ts... >
  >{}> method(Xs&&... plist){
```

where we test if the incoming arguments can be converted into the data stored.

I made another change `forward_as_tuple` instead of `make_tuple`, and `emplace` instead of `push`, both of which are required to make the perfect forwarding go all the way down.

Apologies for any typos in the above code.

Note that in C++1z, we can do without `zip_test` and just have a direct expansion of the test within the `enable_if` by using fold expressions.

Maybe we can do the same in C++11 using `std::all_of` and `constexpr initializer_list<bool>`, but I haven't tried.

`zip` in this context refers to zipping up to lists of the same length, so we pair up elements in order from one to the other.

A significant downside to this design is that it doesn't support anonymous `{}` construction of arguments, while the first design does.  There are other problems, which are the usual failurs of perfect forwarding.

Comment: Well this is incredibly complex :-) Is there any advantage of this solution over using value type in method header?

Comment: @hynner it eliminates needless moves, and only constructs the type once.  So if you have a type that is expensive to move, but the description of it is cheap...  As an example, if one of your types contains a 1000000 element `std::array`, my version can construct it directly in the `vector`.  There can be other advantages if you where not storing the data in a `vector`, like the above handles non-copyable non-movable types.  Overall, I would rarely bother with the above, but it is what is required in C++11/14 to perfect forward with type constraits on each element.

Comment: Right, I didn't immediately realized that even moves can be expensive. Well I'll try to understand whats going on in there and if I'm able to I'll accept your answer. But I guess I'll stick with the value type header just for readability sake since it really isn't **that** performance critical.

Comment: @hynner As nobody else did the simpler solution, I folded it into mine as a prefix.  I also added an appendix highlighting some imperfections in perfect forwarding.

Comment: I've just gone through your code and I understand what it does now. Thanks for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As Yakk says in his answer, there's and "easy" way and a "perfect forwarding" way to do this. They are not identical, but I think he's overcomplicated the situation by fixating on `forward_as_tuple` and `tuple`'s conversion constructors. To wit ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1057a65fdf88b6a2)):

```
template<typename ... Ts>
class A {
public:
  // "Simple" method. Does not perfect forward.
  // Caller's expressions are copied/moved/converted at the callsite
  // into Ts, and then moved (for non-reference types) or copied
  // (reference types) into the vector.
  void simple_method(Ts... ts) {
    // some code 
    std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    // some other code
  }

  // "Perfect forwarding" method.
  // Caller's expressions are perfectly forwarded into the vector via
  // emplace.
  template <typename...Us>
  void perfect_forwarding_method(Us&&...us) {
    // some code 
    std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Us>(us)...);
    // some other code
  }

  // Constraint alias.
  template <typename...Us>
  using Constructible = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_constructible<std::tuple<Ts...>, Us...>::value
  >::type;

  // "Constrained Perfect forwarding" method.
  // Caller's expressions are perfectly forwarded into the vector via
  // emplace. Substitution failure if tuple<Ts...> cannot be constructed
  // from std::forward<Us>(us)...
  template <typename...Us, typename = Constructible<Us...>>
  void constrained_perfect_forwarding_method(Us&&...us) {
    // some code 
    std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Us>(us)...);
    // some other code
  }
};
```

All three methods properly handle lvalue/rvalue reference types in `Ts`.

Comment: @dyp I'm not sure what you mean by "cause issues," but `is_constructible<T, Args...>` is the weakest constraint sufficient for emplacement into a standard container of `T` using the default allocator. `emplace{_front,_back}` all require `EmplaceConstructible`, which requires that `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(m, p, args...)` is valid. For the default allocator that requires `::new((void *)p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` to be valid, for which `is_constructible<T, Args...>` is both sufficient and necessary. Emplacement via the default allocator performs direct initialization.

Comment: Ah, right, the SFINAE checks of `tuple`'s constructor uses `is_convertible`. The requires-clause uses `is_constructible`, but that's probably irrelevant here. I somehow got confused by the weird tuple initialization rules.